# Exclude hidden input value from displaying after search performed

Tags: javascript, forms, concatenation

I am using javascript to concatenate strings to omit products from search results in shopify.
I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent my hidden input value from displaying in the input after the search is performed?

Something like `value="{{ search.terms | escape }} -= q"`? Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
function SubmitForm() {
  var myVendor = "vendor:vendorname";
  var q_Input = document.getElementById("search_form").elements.namedItem("q_input").value;
  document.getElementById("q").value = q_Input + " " + myVendor;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation__search{% if animate %} navigation__entrance-animation{% endif %}">
  <form id="search_form" action="/search" onsubmit="SubmitForm();" name="search" method="get" role="search"><input type="hidden" name="view" value="myvalue" /><input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
    <div class="input-group--underline">
      <input class="input-group__field" type="text" name="q_input" id="q_input" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" aria-label="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" {% if disableTab %} tabindex="-1" {%
        endif %}>
      <input type="hidden" id="q" name="q" value="" />
      <div class="input-group__btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--clear btn--square" {% if disableTab %} tabindex="-1" {% endif %}>
          {% include 'icon-search' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.search.submit' | t }}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```